# Linear independence of certain vectors of $\mathbf{C}^2$ over $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $\{e_1,e_2\}$ where $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$ is the standard basis of $\Bbb C^2$ as a vector space over $\Bbb C$. Show that $\{e_1,ie_1,e_2,ie_2\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb C^2$ as a vector space over $\Bbb R$ and conclude that $\dim_\Bbb R \Bbb C^2=2\dim_\Bbb C \Bbb C^2$.

I know that in general in order to show that a set of vectors form a basis you must show that they are linearly independent and are a spanning set. So normally I would solve $Ax=0$ and if $x$ was $0$ I would know they were linearly independent. However, I'm not sure how to use that here.

Comment: Do you mean to have $\{e_1, ie_1, e_2, ie_2\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the rules:

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ and $ae_1+be_2+ce_1i+de_2i=0$. Then we have:

$$ae_1+be_2+ce_1i+de_2i=0 \iff (a+ci)e_1+(b+di)e_2=0 \iff a,b,c,d=0$$ since we have
$$(a+ci)\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\0 \end{array}\right)+(b+di)\left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\1 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\0 \end{array}\right) \iff a+ci=0,b+di=0$$

and $a+ci,b+di$ are just **complex** numbers since $a,b,c,d$ are **reals** and a complex number $z=x+yi$ with $x,y \in \mathbb R$ is equal $0$ if and only if imaginary and realpart ($Re(z)=x, Im(z)=y$) are equal 0.

So we have that $\mathbb C^2$ over $\mathbb R$ is a $4$ dimensional vector space.

Using the fact $\mathbb C \cong \mathbb R^2 $ you can conclude the claim.

**Edit:**

Even though there is a seperate answer above how to deal with the span I'll give a proof too for the sake of completeness and because I know that sometimes it's good to see the same story twice, so here it is:

Let $z \in \mathbb C^2$ be arbitrary and of the form $z=(z_1,z_2)$ with $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb C$. Since elements in the complex plane consist of a real- and imaginary part we can 'decompose' our $z$ even further by

$$z_1=x_1+y_1i; \space x_1,y_1 \in \mathbb R$$
$$z_2=x_2+y_2i, \space x_2,y_2 \in \mathbb R$$

So we can express our arbitrary $z \in \mathbb C^2$ as follows:

$$z=(z_1,z_2)=(z_1,0)+(0,z_2)=z_1e_1+z_2e_2=(x_1+y_1i)e_1+(x_2+y_2i)e_2=x_1e_1+x_2e_2+y_1e_1i+y_2e_2i$$

And as you can see, we were able to find a way to express an arbitrary (and hence *any*!) element in $\mathbb C^2$ in terms of real valued coefficients and the linear indepentent vectors $\{e_1,e_2,e_1i,e_2i\}$.

Comment: Could you explain how to do the spanning? I've attempted it but I keep ending up with 4 unknowns and 2 equations so I guess I'm setting it up wrong.

Comment: Is everything clear now? Don't be afraid to ask if something is an unclear!:) Note though that Sloan's proof and mine are identical, I just wanted to give you a second view of the same thing to make things more clear. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that has answered my question. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Then you may accept my answer so that we have less open questions on this site. ;) This applies to your other questions too. Accept an answer if you think the question you posed has been well recieved and answered. I saw that you are rather new on math.stackexchange that's why I kindly ask you to.:)

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't realise you could do this, I'll do it now.

Comment: Going back to the top, how did you conclude the a,b,c,d=0? Sorry, I thought I understood it but I guess not

Comment: Have a look now and tell we if you understand it.

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect :)

Comment: @sksks52 may I ask you why you removed the tick without leaving a comment? It's ok if you don't accept the answer, however you should say what part you're not satisfied with or which you don't understand. Otherwise we won't be able to help you any further.

Answer (score 1):

As another user has described linear independence (and hopefully made it clear that $dim_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}^2 = 4 = 2\dim_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}^2$ ), you need now to show that $\{e_1,e_2,ie_1,ie_2\}$ spans $\mathbb{C}^2$. Let $\xi \in \mathbb{C}^2$ be arbitrary. Then, by our assumptions, there exists $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ so that $\xi = x_1e_1+x_2e_2$. Since each $x \in \mathbb{C}$ we can write $x = a + bi$ for $a,b$ real. Hence, \begin{equation}
\xi = x_1e_1+x_2e_2 \\
=(a_1+b_1i)e_1+(a_2+b_2i)e_2 \\
=a_1e_1+b_1ie_1+a_2e_2+b_2ie_2.
\end{equation}
This should complete your proof.